# MS-DOS file sharing

Tags: windows, remote-access, dos

I need to access an MS-DOS machine remotely.
For Windows, such as Windows NT or Windows 2000, I would use SMB/CIFS (the JCIFS library), but for MS-DOS what should be used to access the filesystem?

Comment: Which version of MS-DOS?

Comment: are you allowed to install another operating system to that machine?

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 options:

1. MS-DOS 6.x provides INTERLNK.EXE and INTERSVR.EXE. This can be used to connect a DOS machine via a serial port or parallel port connection with a WinNT, Win2K and WinXP machine.
2. Another option is to install Windows 3.x and Trumpet Winsock. This offers TCP/IP Support thus you can use a NIC Ethernet card. If i remember correctly Windows for Workgroups ships with its own TCP/IP stack and thus doesn't need Trumpet Winsock.
3. You could install Windows 95 or 98. This does definitely have integrated TCP/IP support and will be still be able to run DOS software natively. It's also possible to install Windows 9x besides older MS-DOS versions.
4. Create a second partition and install an operating system with integrated TCP/IP support. You can use Windows NT for this. But Minix, FreeBSD or a Linux system with a low RAM footprint and support for the CPU on your old DOS machine might work too.

EDIT:

Keep in mind that old operating systems like Windows NT or Windows 98 no longer receive security patches. So if you connect them to your LAN, it makes sense to put these computers in their own VLAN and deny them Internet access. VLANs can be created with managed switches.